# Two If statements having a common bool problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two if statements and two bools(bool1 and bool2) in my script.My script is like this-

```
using UnityEngine
using system.collection

public class example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool bool1;
    public bool bool2;

    void Update()
    {
        if (bool1 == true)
        {
            // play animation1
        }
        if (bool1 == true && bool2 == true)
        {
            // play animation2
        }
    }
}
```

I want only animation2 to play when both bools are true not both animation1 and animation2 together.

What should I do?

Comment: if (bool1 == true && bool2 == false) // Play animation 1;    if (bool1 == true && bool2 == true) // Play animation 2

Comment: Comparing a bool with a bool resulting in a bool seems strange to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to rewrite your statement to:

```
if (bool1 == true && bool2 == true)
{
    // play animation2
}
else if (bool1 == true)
{
    // play animation1
}
```

Because your first statement is stronger, i.e. it's true when the second is true, that's why you need to reverse checking of your conditions.

Most developers would ommit the `== true` as it is unnecessary. If you want to check if something is `false`, you can just do `!bool1`. Here is your code without the unnecessary `== true`'s:

```
if (bool1 && bool2)
{
    // play animation2
}
else if (bool1)
{
    // play animation1
}
```

Comment: Did you know that you can simply omit `== true`?

Answer (score 2):

You could go for a bit of nesting, with the added benefit that your bool1 only needs to be evaluated once:

```
if (bool1)
{
    if (bool2)
    {
        // play animation2
    }
    else
    {
        // play animation1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must change condition order.

```
void Update()
{
    if (bool1 && bool2)
    {
        // play animation2
    }
    else if (bool1)
    {
        // play animation1
    }  
}
```